# Possible to assert a list?

Tags: prolog

I would like to ask if it is possible to assert a list instead of singular terms? For example I have tried the following:

```
assert(user_chosen_fruits([Grapes, Apples, Peaches])).
```

However, when I queried using `user_chosen_fruits(X).`, it returns me the following:

```
X = [_4872, _4878, _4884].
```

Am I missing out some output processing, or is my assertion simply wrong? I'm not sure if it is even possible to assert lists. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asserting a list of **variables**, hence the bindings you get when you call `user_chosen_fruits/1`. Try instead:

```
| ?- assertz(user_chosen_fruits(['Grapes', 'Apples', 'Peaches'])).
```

P.S. The `assert/1` predicate is deprecated. Use instead the standard `asserta/1` or `assertz/1` predicates.

Comment: Woah, thank you very much for the fast and accurate answer! That does make sense now that you tell me. Thanks for the heads up on the deprecation warning as well.